# GitHub for Windows - is it open source?

Tags: github-for-windows

Is GitHub for Windows open source? If so, I can't seem to find the repository.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to Tom Preston-Werner, one of the GitHub founders, in his post **["Open Source (Almost) Everything"](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2011/11/22/open-source-everything.html)**, about the open-sourcing philosophy

> Don't open source anything that represents core business value. [...] **Notice that everything we keep closed has specific business value that could be compromised by giving it away to our competitors**. Everything we open is a general purpose tool that can be used by all kinds of people and companies to build all kinds of things.

However, **Hubot**, previsouly a closed-source asset of GitHub, was eventually **[open-sourced](https://github.com/blog/968-say-hello-to-hubot)** in late 2011.

> For the past year or so we've been telling people about Hubot [...] So **we decided to rewrite him from scratch, open source him, and share him with everyone**.

Currently, the Windows Github client is not an open source software... but who knows, it *might* be open-sourced one day.

Comment: Sad ... They've used a ton of open source libraries to build it. There doesn't seem to be much open WCF reactive UI code to learn from.

Comment: As @Lincoln said that's a pity, could have had a great pedagogical value

Answer (score 13):

Phil Haack (who currently works at GitHub) gave a hint in his [blog comments](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx#87318) to this effect:

> At the moment, it is not open source. Many of the libraries we created are open source. As we polish up more and more of those libraries, we'll release more components we used to make the app.

So no, the application is not open source, but keep a look out for some parts of it being published on GitHub. (But bear in mind that this is just a blog comment, not an official announcement of any kind).

Comment: Yeah like gitlib2, good stuff. I prefer linking over parsing almost any day.

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest news, GitHub for Windows is renamed to GitHub Desktop. It is redisigned with Electron and completely open sourced. The beta version has been released. The weblink of GitHub Desktop open source repository leaves here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop .